# Maximum number or characters per select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What is the maximum number of characters that can be used in a SQL statement in oracle?

Comment: What are you trying to do, since you're asking this question?

Comment: I am writing a code to create a dynamic select statement which can be large. I need to limit the size but I do not want to get limit unless exceeds the max limit in oracle.

Comment: Ugh I've seen horrible statements running into many pages, or people typing data into INs instead of using relational methods. More relevant is what your explain plan looks like, and what its cost is.  Try not to write huge dynamic statements as they clutter up oracle's shared pool. Rather be modular in your approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Oracle documentation doesn't give a maximum length for a SQL query. [Check this here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40402/limits003.htm).

This is because the physical limit depends on the OS of the database server. Suffice to say the actual limit will be way bigger than any practical query you could write (or even generate).

There used to be a practical limit for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE of 32767 because that's the limit of a PL/SQL varchar2 variable. But these days we can feed EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with much larger statements using clob. Still doesn't mean we should :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on many things like space in disk and memory etc. But yes you shouldn't put large data in a query. It's not a good option.

Normally following what I said it doesn't require huge characters in the query, which might make you ask this question.